# expand column width of a grid view

Tags: .net, asp.net, excel, grid

HI,

I need to expand column width of the grid view by dragging it to suitable length like we do in excel after selecting a column.Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [Demo](http://mattberseth.com/blog/2007/08/creating_a_gridview_with_resiz.html)